# Share audio between computers over network (like Mouse without Borders)

Tags: windows-7, networking, audio, network-shares

I'm using Mouse without Borders to share my mouse and keyboard between my laptop and desktop. I'd like, at times, to hear the system sounds and multimedia sounds from the laptop on the desktop as well. Is there a program that will allow me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play audio over network with Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/29844/play-audio-over-network-with-windows-7), [Software to act as sound card and transmit across network](http://superuser.com/questions/36449/software-to-act-as-sound-card-and-transmit-across-network), [Is there a way to pipe audio between these two networked computers?](http://superuser.com/questions/154628), [Audio stream from secondary computer](http://superuser.com/questions/425448), [Play audio through another computer's speakers](http://superuser.com/questions/533333) etc.

Comment: Another great solution is provided here: http://sound.stackexchange.com/a/35826/15198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with commercial programs such as [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/) or [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm), or with free programs such as [PulseAudio](http://pulseaudio.org/). See also [Stream Windows audio over the network](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/2723/3647)